# "Failed to handle method call" en Google Maps

Tags: ios, flutter

Estoy tratando de usar el Widget GoogleMap. Utilizo los pasos detallados en "[google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)" y realizo toda la configuración que se solicita. Creo la APIKey de GoogleMaps y agrego la clave en los archivos AndroidManefest y AppDelegate.swift.  Cuando ejecuto en Android me funciona correctamente pero cuando cambio a iOS en el "flutter Inspector" me aparece el error que detallo mas abajo.

```
    Failed to handle method call
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:78)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:51)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      PlatformViewsService.initUiKitView (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:168:41)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _UiKitViewState._createNewUiKitView (package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart:503:71)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _UiKitViewState._initializeOnce (package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart:453:5)
#5      _UiKitViewState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart:463:5)
#6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4086:12)
#7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
#8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
#10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
#11     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
#12     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
#13     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4088:11)
#14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
#15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
#17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
#18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
#19     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
#20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
#21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
#23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
#24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
#25     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
#26     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
#27     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4314:11)
#28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#29     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5233:32)
#30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
#32     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
#33     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
#34     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
#35     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4088:11)
#36     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
#37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
#38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
#39     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
#40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
#41     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
#42     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
#43     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src
```

El metodo build de clase_MyAppState que extiende de State es:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('MyApp'),
          leading: IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Atras',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: _initialPosition,
          markers: _markers,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Los metodos onMapCreated, _initialPosition y _markers

```
void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

CameraPosition _initialPosition = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(-33.4726900, -70.6472400),zoom: 16.0);

final Set<Marker> _markers = Set();
```